# Integral of a gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let's say I have the Laplace equation: $\nabla^2\phi=0$. Does it make any sense to integral both sides? Or is it only solvable writing it as $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}=0$ and then solving a PDE?
Is there any meaning to doing a single integral on a gradient of some scalar function which is dependent upon many variables? How can it be done?

I think my confusion stems from a line integral, where $\int_C \vec{\nabla} \phi \cdot \vec{ds} =\phi(B)-\phi(A)$ considering A is the starting position of the curve C, and B the end. But in any other context, is it applicable somehow?

I will be very glad for someone to put light on this, and maybe end my confusion regarding the connection between integrals and gradients. I'm a physics undergraduate, so I haven't covered this material with mathematical rigor.

Comment: You may integrate. But with respect to which of the variables, and in what order?

Comment: As for the line integral, what you're integrating is the differential form $\phi_x\mathrm dx+\phi_y\mathrm dy+\cdots,$ which is the total differential of $\phi,$ since the coefficients form a gradient. Thus we can write it as $\mathrm d\phi,$ and integrating this is then trivial, for it gives $\phi +c,$ and we can evaluate any desired arc of this curve.

Comment: How will the integration look like, if I choose to integrate it?

Comment: That depends on what variable you want to integrate with respect to.

Comment: In any case, that equation implies that $\nabla \phi=0,$ which tells us that $\phi=c,$ for some constant $c.$

Comment: Isn't it $\phi = C_1 r+C_2$ if $\phi$ is only dependent upon r for example? Anyway, If $\phi$ is dependent upon x,y and z, what's the meaning of $\int \nabla^2 \phi dx$? I fail to see what that will give me, considering $\phi$ is a function of x,y and z, and not x alone.

Comment: Yes, that's one example, but you should understand that by $\phi=0$ I meant $\phi(x,y,z)=0$ really. I don't think your integral would mean much in this case.